# Number of subsets of integers 1 through n (including null set) containing no pair of integers that share a common factor

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find an estimated number of sets of co-primes for all numbers less than n

I am referencing [Cameron and Erdos](http://books.google.com/books?id=68g0Ds4FNM0C&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem 3.3

However it seems the the range is large
for example, for $n = 4$ there are $12$ sets that have co-prime numbers $\le 4$
however based on the theorem, this number is in the range:
$$2^{\pi(n)}.e^{(1/2+O(1))\sqrt n}\; \text{and}\; 2^{\pi(n)}.e^{(2+O(1))\sqrt n}$$

If I ignore $O(1)$ for $n=4$ this is between $16487$ and $331155$.

This is too big. Any ideas or other formulas..

Thanks

Comment: Is "pi(n)" the count of primes less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: pi*n thanks....

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've misunderstood the notation $\pi(n)$ to mean multiplication, when actually the authors intend it to be the prime counting function, the number of primes less than or equal to $n$.  See the argument in Sec. 3.3 right before the Thm. 3.3.that you cite.  Since $\pi(n) \lt n \lt \pi \cdot n$, this could easily have caused the larger estimates you are concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\pi(n)$ I get $10.873$ and $218.393$, which isn't so bad, but the upper bound still looks a bit high.

Comment: What did you use for O(1)?

Comment: $\pi(4)=2, \sqrt 4=2$, calculate $2^2.e^{~(1/2)*2}=4\times 2.718\dots=10.873\dots$. Similarly for the other one.

Comment: Thank you I was miss interpreting pi(n)

Comment: so $\pi(n)$ = n/ln(n)   by the prime number theorem correct?

Comment: $\pi(n) \text{~} \dfrac{n}{\ln n}$ (asymptotic to, not equal to)

Comment: nuffin' to say. i doubt you can get to the formula because you'd need to know the prime distribution, which if you check Riemann's hypothesis out, isn't that easy.